# Trying to find the title of an old movie about a robot like WALL-E

Tags: story-identification, robots

I saw this movie when I was a kid.

At the end of the movie, the robot was left behind in a broken space ship taking care of the plants.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is [Silent Running](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Running), from 1972.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks

Comment: I found that movie quite depressing as a kid.  :-P

Comment: As a side note, the robots in "Silent Running" were portrayed by amputees.  This made the robots less like humans in costume as happens so often in sci-fi films and tv shows.  I think it added to the enjoyment of this film because of the little human charactreristics these robots portrayed without appearing too human.

Comment: Of course, the robots literally were humans in costumes!

Comment: @moopet there should be a special kind of upvote for this kind of comment. So much scifi addresses what it means to be human one way or the other. I'm sure the implication wasn't intentional, but surely the actors were human! :)

Answer (score 16):

It would be easier if you told us a bit more, when were you a kid. But My google-fu threw up this.

[Silent Running](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Running)

It does have the broken space-ship, the robot and the plants.

Kind regards,
Jennifer

Answer (score 3):

I agree.  Sounds like Silent Running, starring Bruce Dern.  I saw it on TV, yes, years ago.  Green apocalypse type of film, with all Earth's plants on a spaceship after Earth got to polluted to sustain them.  When the crew gets the order to blow the ship and come home, Dern's character kills the other crew members and takes off into space with the plants and the robot helpers on board.